# Auto starting application after phone boot does not work in Android 4.4.2,but works in Android 5

Tags: android, autostart

now I want to auto start my app after booting android phone. Now it works in android 5, but does not work in Android 4.4.2.
In Android 4.4.2, only works in case I enable my app in startup manager.
Is there any other way to auto boot without setting in startup manager in Android 4.4.2? 
That is code of my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="MyAppService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Android does not have something called a "startup manager". Please explain **in detail** what you are referring to as a "startup manager". It may be something that is from your device manufacturer, not Android.

Comment: I'm using huawei 4.4.2. and  there is Startup manager option in Setting.

Comment: is this a programming related question?

Comment: That is something unique to either that specific Huawei device, or perhaps all Huawei devices. It is not part of standard Android.

Comment: Yes, that is code of  my Android manifest file.

Comment: <receiver android:name="MyService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Comment: ah, now it´s clear. You should post Your manifest and Your BroadcastReceiver as a part of Your question.....not as comment...

Comment: and one thing: Huawei devices have some extra features like the startup manager and the energy save manager. I think they have implemented that as part of their "translation" from android system. Then, You can do nothing against that the startup manager that does prevent Your app from starting....